How to remove axeswalker after Xpath expression is validated?
At moment we have a process that take files and read them apply the xpath to find some things and for the first files works fine, but then we start to see that memory has a consumption really high until arrive to OOM we check the heap dump and see that instances of axeswalkers are using the memory but the first process finish correctly the others start to take more and more time until we get the OOM. its some suggestion about how to delete this objects axeswalkers some advice will be welcome.
Regards.
we tried to put the reference to documents and builders in null after the xpath is validated but yet receive this objects in memory.

You need to say which XPath processor you are using. There are many XPath processors available for the Java VM. You also need to provide example Java code that demonstrates and reproduces the problem. An extract of your heap dump would also assist.

Hi @MichaelKay we are using the component of camel-xpath the exact version is this one  org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-xpath-starter:jar:3.10.0:compile we download the heap-dump and we see a behavior strange with a BeanInfo that is where the instances stay alive. with a MethodBean in spring-boot context in this moment we have a method that have the next signature
        @Handler
        public void handler(Exchange exchange, @XPath(value = "//*/@val", resultType = String.class) String val,
                        @XPath(value = "//*/@int", resultType = String.class) String interval) throws InvalidDateFormatException 

That little part generate the instances of MethodInfo in this moment we are going to apply a change to make the xpath like usual instead of use the notation in the name of the method and i will back with the diference and if that was the reason to the high consumption of memory.
Regards.
